# Run ASP.NET Core application in "Development" environment

Tags: asp.net-core, project.json, .net-core-rc2

I am using **ASP.NET Core RC2** and when I run `dotnet run` my application always runs in "Production". I am not able to change it to "Development".

I have the following `launchSettings.json` file:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:26088/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MVCCoreRc2App": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure why `dotnet` is running the application in "Production" when I am setting `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"`.

This was working in **ASP.NET Core RC1**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

launchsettings.json is used when launching from Visual Studio, but not from the command line dotnet.exe.

On the console set the environment variable before calling `dotnet run`.

`set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`

Comment: This not seems to be a permanent solution to me. Everytime I need to set this variable. What is I am hosting app with IIS?

Comment: @Vipul, set this variable on your PC rather than at the command line.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Bash, the appropriate line is:

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

You can set this in your `~/.bashrc` file to make it apply whenever you log in.

Answer (score 2):

You can even change the environment at the command line when you run your application as in:

```
dotnet run environment=development
```

Comment: I like this solution the best, means I don't have to mess with the environment variables, just specify it in the command straight up.